# Multiplexing Service Broker messages

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I notice in the documentation for the SEND statement that it allows for sending the same message on multiple conversation handles at once. Let's say that in my situation, the number of places I want to send a given message is small (fewer than 5), but every message I want to send should go to all of those places. Is there any practical difference between the following:

```
declare @ch1 uniqueidentifier,
    @ch2 uniqueidentifier,
    @ch3 uniqueidentifier,
    @message xml;

-- approach #1
send on conversation (@ch1, @ch2, @ch3)
    message type [foo]
    (@message);

-- approach #2
send on conversation (@ch1)
    message type [foo]
    (@message);

send on conversation (@ch2)
    message type [foo]
    (@message);

send on conversation (@ch3)
    message type [foo]
    (@message);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SEND ON (@h1, @h2, @h3, ... , @hN)` is going to store the message body only once in `sys.transmission_queue`. As opposed to `SEND ON (@h1)`, `SEND ON (@h2)`, ... , `SEND ON (@hN)` which will store the message body N times. This is, basically, the real difference. If the message body is of significant size it can have noticeable impact on perf.

For local delivery, when `sys.transmission_queue` is usually not involved, there will be no significant difference.

Comment: That's what I suspected (and was going to corroborate). My issue is that I'm determining which handles (by way of quantity) to send on at run time, so that would mean crafting the send statement dynamically. Not undoable, but also not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I depends on you needs, As you say you have only five conversion you can go both ways . No difference between them... But here is the catch

1. Do you relay want to check your message individually(whether it went or not) OR you want to rollback from certain case or person
2. Do you want to count or do something on the sending process

Your 1st approach is like a machine gun.In small case it wont create pressure or data lose in a server but in large case i can not give you the guaranty(i mean Like machine gun, Server do jam ).

Messages in the transmission queues for an instance are transmitted in sequence based on:

1. The priority level of their associated conversation endpoint.
2. Within priority level, their send sequence in the conversation.